# Variable href links? Images on a timer

Tags: css, image, timer, carousel, var

Hello I have figured out how to create a rotating image carousel on a timer using css, but I do not know how to also make the a href variable. Is it possible to have different links associated with each image? Thank you in advance!

```
<div class="sliderHolder columns-6 floatRight">

<div class="sliderButtonShadow"></div>
<a href="#"><img id="slider" src="image1.jpg" align="middle" class="sliderImage"></a>

 <script type = "text/javascript">

        var image=document.getElementById("slider");
        var currentPos = 0;
        var images = ["image1.jpg","image2.jpg", "image3.jpg"]

        function volgendefoto() {
            if (++currentPos >= images.length) currentPos = 0;
            image.src = images[currentPos];
        }

        setInterval(volgendefoto, 3000);

    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a link to the page, give it an id, then convert your array into an object that has image url's and the link associated with each, and update the `href` of the link when you transition images.

```js
var image = document.getElementById("slider");
var link = document.getElementById('sliderLink');
var currentPos = 0;
var images = [
  { 'img':"http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz1.png",
    'url':'http://image1.com'
  },
  { 'img':"https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/33/3b/4f/333b4f22ae39d1aaf8c23d77e759d8e1.jpg",
    'url':'http://image2.com'
  },
  { 'img':"http://www.star2.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/happy-days-770x470.jpg",
    'url':'http://image3.com'
  }
];

function volgendefoto() {
  if (++currentPos >= images.length) currentPos = 0;
  image.src = images[currentPos].img;
  link.href = images[currentPos].url;
}

setInterval(volgendefoto, 3000);
```

```html
<a id="sliderLink" href="#"><img id="slider" src="http://www.star2.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/happy-days-770x470.jpg" align="middle" class="sliderImage"></a>
```

Comment: It worked! Your answer was very well written thank you so much!